# Yalantis search filter with custom background colour for android

Tags: android

I am using the Yalantis filter for android. I am trying to set a dark background color for the drop down list. I tried to achieve it by doing this:

```
    <com.yalantis.filter.widget.Filter
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I tried setting the background color but unfortunately, the filter is still white and this is the result.[image]

As you can see, underneath specialties is where the color appears. I Want the filter itself to have this color instead but the filter still looks like this:

[image]

The filter is still white. Is there a way to change the filter color? Thank you.

Comment: jsut follow the sample [here](https://github.com/Yalantis/SearchFilter)

Comment: That is the sample I followed. What I am asking is can the background color for the filter be changed, not the colors for the filter items. I know how to change that of course. They gave the code in the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review the 1.0.3 version of the library, it's already fixed. Now you can easily change the background using `expandedBackground` and `collapsedBackground` attributes

```
<com.yalantis.filter.widget.Filter
    app:expandedBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:collapsedBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```